# VB.Net 2013 (VB fail to search the access database)

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have this weird problem when I register using my system I developed in VB.NET, it does not allow me to login(in the login form) using the correct username and password I registered. However, when I manually input the username and password inside the Access database, I manage to login without any problem. Here are the codes of my login and register

Login

```
 conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=    C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SDP user interface\SDP user interface\bin\Debug\SCPdatabase.accdb")

  conn.Open()

    sql = "Select * FROM Members WHERE Username ='" & txtusername.Text & "' AND [Password] ='" & txtpassword.Text & " ' "

    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If dr.HasRows Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login Success")
        Me.Hide()
        Member_Page.Show()
        Member_Page.lblwelcome.Text = "Welcome" & txtusername.Text
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed")
    End If

    dr.Close()
    conn.Close()
```

Register

```
    Dim flag As Integer

    MyConn.Open()

    sql = "Insert INTO Members (Username,[IC],Email,PhoneNumber,FullName,[Password],Newsletter) values (' " & txtusername3.Text & "','" & txtic3.Text & "','" & txtemail3.Text & "','" & txtphone3.Text & "','" & txtname3.Text & "', ' " & txtpwd3.Text & " ',' " & cmb3.Text & " ')"

    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, MyConn)

    flag = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    If flag > 0 Then

        MessageBox.Show(flag & " records added", "Add Records Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
    MyConn.Close() 'closes the connection
```

Please advice thnx

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` statement is adding whitespace characters to the values:

```
' " & txtusername3.Text & "'
 ^--- here
```

and

```
' " & txtpwd3.Text & " '
 ^--- here            ^--- here
```

etc.

But then when you select from the table, you don't include them:

```
WHERE Username ='" & txtusername.Text & "' AND [Password] ='" & txtpassword.Text & " '
                                                                       just here ---^
```

Get rid of the whitespace characters entirely, as they're changing the values from what you expect those values to be.

Or, better yet, use [query parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx) so you don't have to manually build these string values in the first place.  (And, as a bonus, would close the enormous SQL injection vulnerability you currently have.)

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem quickly.